# Using ParseInt() with JTextField.getText() throwing errors

Tags: java

I am currently trying to receive an input from a `JTextField` and store it as an integer in my data. When I use `ParseInt()`, an error message pops up

> Invalid SSN

but when I hardcode my variable SSN with the same text I enter to the `JTextField`, it works.

Here's the specific section:

```
try {
    ssn = Integer.parseInt(ssnText.getText());
    //ssn = 123456789;
    if((Integer.toString(ssn).length()) != 9)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid SSN","Invalid SSN", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        ssnText.setText("");
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, your error message is only going to occur if the length of `ssn` is not equal to `9` - I suggest either using a debugger or print statement to print the state of your variables and logic flow

Comment: Yea... I've been plugging in only 9 digit numbers to the textfield but still throws the error, unless I hardcode the same 9 digit number in.. Thanks for the suggestions, I'll try using a debugger

Comment: Return the incorrect value from `ssnText.getText()` as part of the error message. An error message with no details is almost as frustrating as no error at all.

Comment: Where is this code run from? An event for the JTextField in question? Also, if you are going to display your Message Dialog from your GUI then use `this` for the parent component instead of `null`.